# Using Regex.Match static method to find a match starting at a specific position

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching, match

Microsoft offers a method called [Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3583dcyh.aspx) that matches a Regex pattern starting at a specific position in the input string. What I am trying to do is optimize the performance of my program by using the [static method version of Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz.aspx), there by gaining the benefit of caching. There does not seem to be a way to specify a specific position to start matching though, even though the member version does. Is there anyway to emulate this or is there an alternate static method I'm missing that allows me to start searching for my pattern at a specific spot in the input string? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you need optimization?  Is the difference of a few milliseconds really significant?  You don't want to spend a lot of effort on something and not get a payback.

Comment: Well right now, my program is parsing about 1000 matches per second, according to the Visual Studio profiler. It isn't a "necessity" per se to get my optimization up, but the faster, the better, right?

Comment: You can specify `RegexOptions.Compiled` when creating the regular expression and use the "member version" of the Match method.  This provides more or less the same effect as the "caching" behavior by the regular expression engine.

Comment: Try profiling to see how much real gain you are having from using static version. In most of the cases it is a trifle and distracts you from focusing on real problems.

Comment: Very simple, using substring from a start index before passing to Match

Comment: @Peter - I did that and I got pretty much the same results for some reason. I did not try CompileToAssembly though because I'd like to keep my program self contained without having another file.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot - You were right. Using Static call did not increase the speed by very much at all, if at all

Comment: Are you using the same pattern match each time, if so can't you just store a static instance of a precompiled reged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a disassembler tool like DotPeek to look inside the System.dll, you'll see that the implementation of the static function creates a new Regex object:

```
public static Match Match(string input, string pattern)
{
  return new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.None, true).Match(input);
}

public static Match Match(string input, string pattern, RegexOptions options)
{
  return new Regex(pattern, options, true).Match(input);
}
```

So in fact it's just the opposite - the static function has worse (or at least not better) performance.

Comment: It does in fact create a Regex object, however, [according to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.cachesize.aspx), the static Regex calls maintain a cache of 15 (by default) expressions. Its true that the first time you call the static Match() method, it may be slower. However matching text using the same Regex should be faster since its cache and the Regex library doesn't need to recompile the expression.

Comment: I just copy pasted the implementation of the static method - the only thing it does is to create an instance and call Match on the instance. If there is caching it is in the instance method or it's not there.

Comment: In fact this link talks about the cache size - the cache is the one used when you specify RegexOptions.Compiled - you can specify that option on instance creation. So again - no difference - the static method is just a convenience.

Comment: According to that link, it specifically says "compiled regular expressions used in static method calls"

Comment: I don't know what MSDN mean. Maybe it means when you use regex in static methods - who knows. What I DO know is that what runs is the System.dll, (which I copy pasted from) and not the MSDN :)